# Create html from two parts of strings

Tags: javascript

I have two strings. The first one looks like:

```
const scriptsStr = '<script src="/build/lib.min.js"></script>';
```

A second one  looks like :

```
const htmlStr = '<html><head></head><body>Some markup</body></html>';
```

I need to paste scriptsStr before closing  tag in htmlStr and then put it into iframe. 
How can I parse htmlStr to find  closing tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlStr.replace('<head>', '<head>' + scriptsStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`htmlStr.indexOf("</html>")` will give you the index of the closing tag.

You can then use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in order to insert `scriptStr` at this index.

Since splice doesn't exist for string, you can implement it :

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start, delCount, newSubStr) {
    return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
};
```

Or, as suggested by dustytrash :

`htmlStr.replace('<head>', '<head>' + scriptsStr);` to insert after opening tag.

or

`htmlStr.replace('</head>', 'scriptsStr + </head>');` to insert before closing tag.

Comment: Although it probably won't break sites in modern browsers, it's considered bad practice to include scripts outside of `head` or `body`

Answer (score 0):

This will find the index of the closing body tag and insert your `scriptsStr` string in that spot

```
const scriptsStr = '<script src="/build/lib.min.js"></script>';
const htmlStr = '<html><head></head><body>Some markup</body></html>';
const indexToInsert = htmlStr.indexOf('</body>');

const newString = htmlStr.substr(0, indexToInsert) + scriptsStr + htmlStr.substr(indexToInsert);
```